# Why does my Swiffy html5 exported file zoom in on the page?

Tags: css, html, google-swiffy

I have used the online Swiffy tool to convert a SWF file.

It all looks perfect when I use the code supplied, however I wanted it to be responsive, so changed the fixed size of the container to 100% width, and auto height.

Now when I view the file the whole canvas seems to slowly zoom in from tiny until it fills the page.

Whats happening here? Why does it insist on animating itself into position rather than just appear filling the screen width?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problem. Check this line carefully:

```
<div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 176px; height: 208px">
```

Make sure not to add anything after "208px".